# Nested schema for an association table

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I'm having trouble serializing my `Joke` data with a schema when I've added an association table.

Here is my model it allows users to enter a joke and also a tag for categorizing the joke:

```
class Joke(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    joke_name = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False)
    joke = db.Column(db.String(5000), nullable=False)
    joke_owner = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    joke_category = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'), nullable=True)
    joke_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    joke_edited = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    tags = db.relationship('JokeTag', secondary=tag_joke, backref=db.backref('jokes', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic',
            primaryjoin=tag_joke.c.joke_id==id,
            secondaryjoin=tag_joke.c.joketag_id==JokeTag.id)


class JokeTag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag = db.Column(db.String(25), nullable=False)
    tag_owner = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
```

Here is my association table that connects the two on a many-to-many basis:

```
tag_joke = db.Table('tag_joke', 
        db.Column('joke_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('joke.id')),
        db.Column('joketag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('joke_tag.id'))
        )
```

I am trying to serialize the data by using the following schema:

```
class TagJokeSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('joke_id', 'joketag_id')



class JokeSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'joke_name', 'joke', 'joke_owner', 'joke_category', 'joke_created', 'joke_edited', 'tags')

        tags=ma.Nested(TagJokeSchema, many=True)
```

I am doing something wrong with the schema because when I try to serialize the data with this:

```
allnotes = Joke.query.filter_by(joke_owner=1).all()
result = jokes_schema.dump(allnotes)
```

I get this TypeError:

`TypeError: Object of type AppenderBaseQuery is not JSON serializable`

When I try to access the jokes and tags from the python command line I am able to access the Joke and corresponding tags.  Although when I try and print a joke it does look a little crazy:

```
Joke('35','No reason','Finance people get buff for no reason.  Just to work on Excel spreadsheets.','1','55', None, None, SELECT joke_tag.id AS joke_tag_id, joke_tag.tag AS joke_tag_tag, joke_tag.tag_owner AS joke_tag_tag_owner 
FROM joke_tag, tag_joke 
WHERE tag_joke.joke_id = %s AND tag_joke.joketag_id = joke_tag.id)
```

I was hoping to get a cleaner print with tags nested in there if they have them.

edit for @Greg0ry:
The printout of allnotes looks like this:

```
[Joke('25','Test Joke','Knock, Knock, Whos There, test joke','1','55', None, None, SELECT joke_tag.id AS joke_tag_id, joke_tag.tag AS joke_tag_tag, joke_tag.tag_owner AS joke_tag_tag_owner FROM joke_tag, tag_joke WHERE tag_joke.joke_id = %s AND tag_joke.joketag_id = joke_tag.id), Joke('35','No reason','Finance people get buff for no reason.  Just to work on Excel spreadsheets.','1','55', None, None, SELECT joke_tag.id AS joke_tag_id, joke_tag.tag AS joke_tag_tag, joke_tag.tag_owner AS joke_tag_tag_owner FROM joke_tag, tag_joke WHERE tag_joke.joke_id = %s AND tag_joke.joketag_id = joke_tag.id)]
```

I also have this within my `Joke` class that explains the printout, I got this from a youtube tutorial I found I believe (Corey Shafer):

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Joke('{self.id}','{self.joke_name}','{self.joke}','{self.joke_owner}','{self.joke_category}', {self.joke_created}, {self.joke_edited}, {self.tags})"
```

as far as db.Model, I may not understand what you're looking for but I have this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Hopefully there's a way to guide me a little more on what you're looking for?

Also if I look for a particular joke by doing

```
jokequery = Joke.query.filter_by(joke_owner=1, id=595).first()
```

I get

```
Joke('595','test joke','knock knock whos there test joke','1','475', None, None, SELECT joke_tag.id AS joke_tag_id, joke_tag.tag AS joke_tag_tag, joke_tag.tag_owner AS joke_tag_tag_owner 
FROM joke_tag, tag_joke 
WHERE tag_joke.joke_id = %s AND tag_joke.joketag_id = joke_tag.id)
```

obviously the last part of that looks pretty bad.  This is because `tags` is an `AppenderBaseQuery`

but if I run this:

```
jokequery.tags.all()
```

the output looks great and is a list which is JSON serializable:

```
[JokeTag('45', 'stackoverflow', '1')]
```

But how do I set this up so that I can send in that list to be serialized and not the query?

Comment: In my apps I'm not using sqlalchemy in the way you do, so it's difficult for me to reason about error message you get. Can you share more context? I'd love to see implementation of db.Model (I assume this is done by you, and in there you linked the `query` method), also I guess `allnotes` is collected OK, can you show the printout what gets returned there?

Comment: @Greg0ry I added in an edit.  It may not be exactly what you're looking for, but hopefully its helpful.  I have to go to work so I may not be able to reply until later.

Comment: @Greg0ry it kind of hit me you may be asking about the Joke.query.filter_by is looking at?  You mean the `class Joke` in my first code block?

Comment: I was thinking about error that says the result of `AppenderBaseQuery` is not JSON serializable. I'm guessing `AppenderBaseQuery` is something defined in `db.Model`?

In my apps I usually add base model which I then use as base class for all models through the app, is that not how your app is structured?

Comment: @Greg0ry -- I actually don't have any base models but I see other examples doing that.  I think I'm heavily influenced by a tutorial i went through that didn't do that.  I'm thinking I might have to create a new project from scratch.  I didn't define what `AppenderBaseQuery` is.

Comment: Hmm... I was hoping your stack is similar to what I'm used to work with but I'm not familiar with `AppenderBaseQuery`... Sorry I'm not much of help this time... If you had minimal working example I would tinker around :)

Comment: It probably won't solve your current problem, but backref is legacy, and you might get better results and help using the modern back_populates keyword. I also think your primary_join and secondary_join might not be necessary as it's a convoluted way to write joke.tags.id = tag.id and reverse with all ids being primary in their collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `lazy='dynamic'` [setting](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.lazy) on the relationship which

> ... will return a pre-configured Query object for all read operations ...

We can remove this setting (and also replace the legacy `backref`):

```py
# Some columns removed for brevity and readability.

class JokeTag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag = db.Column(db.String(25), nullable=False)
    tag_owner = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    jokes = db.relationship('Joke', secondary='tag_joke', back_populates='tags')


class Joke(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    joke_name = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False)
    joke = db.Column(db.String(5000), nullable=False)
    joke_owner = db.Column(
        db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False
    )
    tags = db.relationship(
        'JokeTag',
        secondary=tag_joke,
        back_populates='jokes'
    )
```

If you would prefer to retain the `lazy='dynamic'` setting, you can post-process the serialised output to get the result of the query:

```py
...
class JokeSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'id',
            'joke_name',
            'joke',
            'joke_owner',
            'joke_category',
            'joke_created',
            'joke_edited',
            'tags',
        )

        tags = ma.fields.Nested(TagJokeSchema, many=True)

    # Assuming ma in the question is Marshmallow

    @ma.post_dump
    def dump_tags(self, obj, **kw):
        obj['tags'] = [t.name for t in obj['tags'].all()]
        return obj
```